# Loop in disconnected diagram not showing with tikz-feynman

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman, feynman

I am trying to make the following disconnected diagram using tikz-feynman

[image: Disconnected diagram]

My attempt:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{feynman}[large]
            \vertex [anchor = north](a) {$t'$};
            \vertex [anchor = north, right = of a] (b) {$t$};
            \vertex (d) at ($(a)!0.5!(b)$);
            \vertex [small, dot, below = of d] (c) {};
            \diagram*{(a) --[fermion] (b),
                (c) -- [fermion,loop, in = 45, out  = 135, min distance = 1cm] (c) -- [fermion,loop, out = -45, in  = -135, min distance = 1cm] (c)};
        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output
[image: output of mwe]

As you can see, the fermion loops do not show up! Why is that, and how can i fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Do you want to use only tikz-feynman or prefer to use another package?

Comment: @Sebastiano A clean solution using only tikz-feynman would be desirable

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I not like the tips of the arrows in the curved graph. :-(, I'm sorry. Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround Solution**

I found a way to do this, but I don't really like it, so improvements are welcome.

By creating a new vertex `(d)` on the same position as `(c)`, it all of a sudden works.

**Code**

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{feynman}[large]
            \vertex [anchor = north](a) {$t'$};
            \vertex [anchor = north, right = of a] (b) {$t$};
            \vertex (d) at ($(a)!0.5!(b)$);
            \vertex [small, dot, below = of d] (c) {};
            \vertex (d) at (c);
            \diagram*{(a) --[fermion] (b),
                (c) -- [fermion,loop, in = 45, out  = 135, min distance = 1cm] (d) -- [fermion,loop, out = -45, in  = -135, min distance = 1cm] (c)};
        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Disconnected diagram]